# How to add ngshow directive inside compile/link?

Tags: angularjs

I want to add ngshow in the following custom element in a dynamic way... How to do that?

```
<toggler on-enable="main.enable()" on-disable="main.disable()">
  <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#2fa">
    <on>On state</on>
    <off>Off state</off>
  </div>
</toggler>

cf.directive('toggler', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            state: true,
            onEnable: '&',
            onDisable: '&'
        },
        compile: function (elem, attrs) {
            var onElem = elem.find('on');
            var offElem = elem.find('off');
            // WANT TO DO THIS
            // onElem.ngShow = 'state';
            // offElem.ngShow = '!state';
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Did you try `elem.attr('ng-show', 'state')` ? Not sure it is included in jqLite or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it in the wrong way. Don't forget a rule of thumb in AngularJS: avoid DOM manipulation when it's not mandatory.

I guess that `<on>` and `<off>` are also custom directives, because you can't simply add tags without any defined behaviour. So, why don't put the `ngShow` attribute directly in this directives? Then, a directive's controller (see the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)) will handle the communication between `<on>`/`<off>` and `<toggler>`:

```js
myApp.directive('toggler', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            state: '=',
        },
        controller : [
            '$scope',
            function ($scope) {
                this.isOn = function () {
                    return $scope.state;
                };
            },
        ],
    };
});

myApp.directive('on', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: '^toggler',
        template: '<div ng-show="isOn()" ng-transclude />',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        link : function ($scope, element, attributes, togglerController) {
            $scope.isOn = togglerController.isOn;
        },
    };
});

myApp.directive('off', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: '^toggler',
        template: '<div ng-hide="isOn()" ng-transclude />',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        link : function ($scope, element, attributes, togglerController) {
            $scope.isOn = togglerController.isOn;
        },
    };
});
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/Duwjc/)</kbd>

This way, you will be able to simply unit test your toggler, and extend his behaviour when needed.